# How do I install this program: libQtGui.so.4

Tags: software-installation

I need this,

libQtGui.so.4

but don't know how to get it....

(Yes, I am a primitive user.)

Answer (score 2):

you should be able to use the `terminal` app.

There are other questions and answers about how to set sudo password etc. but you should be able to do this:

- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo app-get install libqtgui4`

Hopefully that works for you

Comment: @Marcus is this answer correct? If so please mark it as the answer.